# IDEA turn off automatically format html

Tags: intellij-idea

in html file, there is a piece of javascript like:

```
{text: "EmployeeManagement", icon: "code", children: [
    {text: "HR", link: [[@{/employeeManage/hr.html}]]},
    {text: "Developer", link: [[@{/employeeManage/developer.html}]]},
]},
```

However, once I put a

```
if(isEmployer) {
}
```

around it, it formats the above code like:

```
if (isEmployer) {
                {
                    text: "EmployeeManagement", children
                :
                    [
                        {text: "HR", link: [[@{
                    /employeeManage
                    /hr.html
                }
                ]]
                },
                    {
                        text: "Developer", link
                    :
                        [[@{
                        /employeeManage
                        /developer.html
                    }
                    ]]
                    }
```

How to turn off this automatically form?
EDIT: This is the file structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>

    ....
</head>
<body data-module="app" style="overflow: hidden">
<div id="desktop"></div>
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/

    var isEmployer = ...

   ...
   {text: "EmployeeManagement", icon: "code", children: [
    {text: "HR", link: [[@{/employeeManage/hr.html}]]},
    {text: "Developer", link: [[@{/employeeManage/developer.html}]]},
   ]},
    ...
```

Comment: Could you post your html file? So we can understand where is the script and If is in the <script> tag.

Comment: @Dhn done, after EDIT: mark.

Comment: are you pasting or typing the `if(isEmployer) {` part?

Comment: @pezetem right, once you type or past a }, it formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to have this behaviour (I guess it is by adding `}`) go to

Editor -> General -> Smart Keys and disable option `Reformat block on typing }`